# Is there an off-the-shelf way to make Sfl4j / Logback to log a message only when it changes?

Tags: java, logging, logback, slf4j

My java app depends on a 3rd party library. This library logs with Slf4j. When the logger corresponding to the package of the library is set to INFO this kind of log is produced:

```
14:20:49.736 [scheduling-1] INFO  i.i.s.m.a.m.MeterRegistryService - collectNumberOfApplications - Publishing the number of active applications '1' and disabled ones '0'.
14:20:54.739 [scheduling-1] INFO  i.i.s.m.a.m.MeterRegistryService - collectNumberOfApplications - Publishing the number of active applications '1' and disabled ones '0'.
14:20:59.742 [scheduling-1] INFO  i.i.s.m.a.m.MeterRegistryService - collectNumberOfApplications - Publishing the number of active applications '1' and disabled ones '0'.
14:21:04.745 [scheduling-1] INFO  i.i.s.m.a.m.MeterRegistryService - collectNumberOfApplications - Publishing the number of active applications '1' and disabled ones '0'.
14:21:09.748 [scheduling-1] INFO  i.i.s.m.a.m.MeterRegistryService - collectNumberOfApplications - Publishing the number of active applications '1' and disabled ones '0'.
```

So I was wondering if there is some slf4j or logback built-in feature that would log this line only if the body of the message changes compared to the previous line. I know I probably can do it with some custom made appender, or extending some already esisting component, keeping track of the hashes of the previous n messages written by a certain logger and actually log only if the the logger is writing the first occurrence of a message, but I would prefer an already made solution if available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In logback there is an out of the box filter that you can use for this called `DuplicateMessageFilter`. This filters out exact duplicate messages. You can make use of a specified threshold on how many repititions you want (through the `allowedRepititions` property)

Just add this filter in your logback configuration and the duplicates should be removed.

Example of the logback config:

```
<configuration>

  <turboFilter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.DuplicateMessageFilter" allowedRepetitions="1"/>

  <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
  </root>  
</configuration>
```

More info:
https://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#DuplicateMessageFilter